# How to erase data before selling a Kindle?

Tags: kindle, security

I plan to sell my old Kindle Keyboard and I want to erase all the Kindle's data ( my books, my personal info, wi-fi passwords...) before. Is it enough to deregister the Kindle and execute a factory reset? Would it completely erase everything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After deregistering the device and executing factory reset  the Kindle looks empty. It shows none of my earlier books.

I've connected the Kindle to a Linux computer and copied all the information to a huge (3.2GB) file:

`dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=afterfactoryreset.dat bs=1M`

One of the books I've read on this device is Zendegi ( by Greg Egan ) so I've searched for the string zendegi which appears quite a few times:

```
$ strings afterfactoryreset.dat | grep -i zendegi
;/mnt/us/documents/Zendegi-asin_B003NE5TVU-type_EBOK-v_0.azwt
;/mnt/us/documents/Zendegi-asin_B003NE5TVU-type_EBOK-v_0.azwt
Zendegi
Zendegi
LAST_BOOK_READ=/mnt/us/documents/Zendegi-asin_B003NE5TVU-type_EBOK-v_0.azw
;/mnt/us/documents/Zendegi-asin_B003NE5TVU-type_EBOK-v_0.azwsq
;/mnt/us/documents/Zendegi-asin_B003NE5TVU-type_EBOK-v_0.mbpsr
</mnt/us/documents/Zendegi-asin_B003NE5TVU-type_EBOK-v_0.apnxsq
;/mnt/us/documents/Zendegi-asin_B003NE5TVU-type_EBOK-v_0.azwsq
...
```

It was very easy to create a script which lists most of the books previously installed on the device:

```
$ strings afterfactoryreset.dat | grep -i '^mnt/us/documents' | rev | cut -d "." -f2- | rev | sort | uniq
mnt/us/documents/A Clash of Kings A Song of Ice a-asin_B000FC1HBY-type_EBOK-v_0
...
mnt/us/documents/Zendegi-asin_B003NE5TVU-type_EBOK-v_0
```

It's not a perfect list but clearly shows that factory reset does not erase all the information.

There are [several ways](https://superuser.com/q/19326/8240) to wipe the empty space of the filesystem. A very simple (not that secure) way is to create a huge files filled with zeroes and delete it:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/mounted/kindle/hugefile.dat
sync
rm /path/to/mounted/kindle/hugefile.dat
```

After that the script does not list the previously installed books.

Comment: Excellent research.  Bravo.

Answer (score 9):

Every Kindle has a menu option "Reset to Factory Defaults", which does exactly what you want: It removes all user specific data from the device.

[Step by step instructions for factory resets on various Kindle devices](http://www.hard-reset.com/amazon-kindle-hard-reset.html)

For the paranoid: Most devices will not actually erase your data, but just mark it as "erased". For the user both are the same thing - if you sell your device, the new owner will not see your stuff. For anybody with sufficient knowledge and interest in that piece of information - such as crime scene investigators etc. - it usually is possible to restore data. I have not checked if a Kindle will actually overwrite your data or leave traces behind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Reset to Factory Defaults` to reset your Kindle:

> Menu button > Settings > Menu button > Reset to Factory Defaults

If for some reason the `Reset to Factory Defaults` option is not working for you (I had a hard time accessing it with a partially broken screen), you can also reset the kindle from the `Device Password` lockscreen prompt:

> Menu button > Settings > Device Password > Set *any* password ("abc")
>
> Press power button to sleep, then again to wake.
>
> At the lockscreen password prompt, type `resetmykindle` as your password.

The "password" `resetmykindle` initiates the `Reset to Factory Defaults` feature.

Answer (score 1):

This is not 100% correct

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/mounted/kindle/hugefile.dat
```

You should replace the data with random numbers, not zeroes.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/path/to/mounted/kindle/hugefile.dat
```